# Choosing data type for date and time in mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, date, time

I have a table which will have a date/time column to store create date of the post. 
what should be the datatype of the column? i found a lot of types like timestamp, date, datetime and so on.
Which one is more compatible (in terms of time conversions) with php and javascript.
how do i convert a mysql date/time to php date/time to javascript date/time?

How do i consider/include the timezone aspect with the time?

Comment: I hope you're not using the mysqli_ set of functions. Use PDO.

Comment: It depends on you requirement, if you particular about Dates only not the time, then choose `Date` and if you are working if with Date + Time then you can use `datetime`

Comment: And need for timezone check this out http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your application is going to be dealing with time zones, You would be better using timestamp.
This will ensure that all the dates are stored in UTC time and will be converted to the current time zone upon retrieval.

Comment: if i use timestamp.. i get an output in this format.. YYYY-MM-DD HH:mi:ss - how do i convert this to its equivalent javascript time?  or which format is better to be sent from php to js so as to convert it easily.. pls advice

Comment: Well there are many ways to do so.
here is a function that would take care of the conversion in the client side http://www.finefrog.com/2009/01/31/convert-a-mysql-date-string-into-javascript-date-object/